# How to find fibonancci series through iteration?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

I write a function to find n'th fibonancci . Codes here -

```
def fib(n):
    res1 = 0
    res2 = 0
    for i in str(n):
        res1 = n - 1
        for j in str(n):
            res2 = n - 2
    return res1 + res2
```

Through the above code, if i enter n = 4 than it prints 5. Thats correct. But if i print n = 5 than it prints 7, it's not correct. How to fix the bugs here. Is there any logical error? Can anyone explain in details.

*Don't use recursive method I want it to do with iteration.*

Comment: This might help you more than a correct solution written by someone else: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: What is the purpose of using `str(n)` ?

Comment: Int object isn't itterable  @wolf

Comment: Yes, now `5` becomes `'5'` which is iterable but has still only one element. I'd suggest learning a bit more basic python before implementing `fib`.

Comment: Yeah . Thanks . I'll

Answer (score 1):

```
def fib(n):
    a,b = 1,1
    for i in range(n-1):
        a,b = b,a+b
    return a

print(fib(4))
```

Well, there is a TechnoBeans page showing you [5 Ways of Fibonacci in Python](https://technobeans.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/5-ways-of-fibonacci-in-python/).

Your code:

```
def fib(n):
    res1 = 0
    res2 = 0
    for i in str(n):     # i gets the string value 9 here
        res1 = n-1       # res1 is 9-1 which is 8
        for j in str(n): # j gets the string value 9 here
            res2= n -2   # res2 is 9-2 which is 7 
    return res1 +res2    # returns 8 + 7 which is 15

print(fib(9))            # output 15
```

You have a lot of unnecessary things in your code, you first need some basic understanding of Python. I personally found the following site very helpful to learn Python:
[Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

To understand why your code doesn't do Fibonacci you need to understand how Fibonacci works. You can read more about Fibonacci at 
[Fibonacci Sequence](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html) on *Math Is Fun* site.

Comment: @Tristan If you use *this* and *here* for links, then there is no chance to recover it if the contents moves (got archived). @Do0msDay *`To understand why your code doesn't do Fibonacci`* - I don't think so, some basic python understanding isn't negligible.

Comment: @Wolf I agree, he has alot of unnecessary things in his code. I was not sure how to approach it.

Comment: I tried my best to integrate the page titles (this is often what you google for) in a readable manner. I hope you appreciate my changes :)

Comment: @Wolf Ah, I see thanks!